# paintComponent() Function Calling

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, jpanel

Here is my code, and its working perfect and draws shapes in `JFrame`. Every method is calling by its name and in my program I did not call any  `paintComponent()` method. So where is the calling method of `paintComponent()` method?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class drawings extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Shapes");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setBounds(150, 10, 1000, 700);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(new drawings());
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(20, 10, 200, 100);
        g.setColor(Color.magenta);
        g.fill3DRect(230, 10, 200, 100, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be easily answered by reading the offical documentation, [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roughly. When you use UI components, a UI thread is started that manages different kind of events. Among these events, there is some related to the visibility of your panel, and when, for example, the host graphic system want your panel to be visible it sends a event to your application to request the drawing of the panel, then the UI thread calls back the appropriate `paint()` method which in turn calls `paintComponent()`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually explicitly call the method. The program decides for itself when the method needs to be called. It usually happens when changes occur.

If you by some chance want to force it to repaint, simply call the method `repaint()` inside your view class (or on that object).

Also inside your `paintComponent()` method, make sure that the first thing you do is call `super.paintComponent()`.